# How to create a new file format?

Tags: json, xml

I have to create a file format which holds some data, and it is to be opened by a particular application (college project).I have an empty grid. When a file is opened, it should contain the number of cells to be displayed on the grid, and in what shape, and other details. After that it should load specific numbers into some specific cells, which will also be present in the file. How do I create a file format for this? Or is it better to just not to create a special file format and rather move on with existing ones?

Comment: Existing file formats would certainly allow you to use existing tools to read/write them.  So unless there's a compelling reason to define your own format, it's probably best to use an existing one.  If you do want to define your own format then you can define it however you want.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

- A file format is nothing but a previously agreed data structure. You can use any data structure, including plain text, as a data format.
- You typically want your format to handle future extensions, so extensible formats such as JSON, YAML, or XML would be ideal. You can also use existing libraries to read and write in those formats.
- If you allow users to add binary media into your file format (such adding images in a Microsoft Word document), you need to bundle your configuration (e.g., a JSON file), media (e.g., JPGs, PNGs, MOV, etc.), and other external sources (e.g., scripts) in a folder structure, and compress them (e.g., zip, gz, tar). Most modern file formats, including Microsoft Word Docx, are essentially zip files.
- You may want to use a file extension. It is not mandatory but customary (typically 3 letters) and has usability benefits (e.g., icons and default applications).

  - If your custom file format is only a JSON file, simply using `.json` extension would be your best choice.
  - It's ill-advised to use a reuse an established file extension for a new file format. Here's a good list of filename extensions that you don't want to use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions
- Consider versioning your file format by adding a version attribute to your configuration.